# no rule to make target `glsldshders.o`, needed by`openframework`

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

```
make: *** No rule to make target `glslshaders.o', needed by `openglframework'.  Stop.
```

Who can help?!!

Here is my make file:

```
# GNU (everywhere)

CC = gcc -g -Wall

# GNU (faster)

#CPP = gcc -O5 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math 

UNAME := $(shell uname) 

ifeq ($(UNAME),) 
UNAME := MINGW 
endif 

EXECUTABLE = openglframework 

OBJS = openglframework.o glslshaders.o glm.o 

ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin) 

LIBS = -lm -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT 

else 

ifeq ($(findstring MINGW,$(UNAME)),MINGW) 

CC += -Iincludes -DNEED_GLEW -DGLEW_STATIC 


OBJS += glew.o 
LIBS = -lm -lopengl32 -lglu32 -Llibs -lfreeglut

else 
LIBS = -lm -lGL -lglut -lGLU

endif 

endif 

### TARGETS 
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS) 
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o $@ 
depend: 
    make.dep 
clean: 
    - /bin/rm -f *.bak *~ $(OBJS) $(EXECUTABLE) $(EXECUTABLE).exe 
make.dep: 
    $(CC) -MM $(OBJS:.o=.c) > make.dep 
### RULES

.SUFFIXES: 
    .c .cpp .o .in .ppm .png .jpg .gif 
.cpp.o: 
    $(CC) -c $< .c.o: $(CC) -c $< 

### DEPENDENCIES 
include make.dep
```

Comment: FYI no need to add backquotes on every line of code - just highlight the whole block of code (or makefile contents in this case) and hit the `{}` button.

Comment: Is `glslshaders.c` present in makefile's directory?

Comment: yes `glslshader.c` is in the makefile's directory..

Comment: `.cpp.o: ` you probably meant `.c.o:`, but default one should exist in any case, unless something messed up.

Comment: `.c.o:` is right behind $< , I forgot to press enter. I think I messed up something indd.. but dunno what:(

Comment: you could use `make -d`, which will report a lot of debugging information. If you wouldn't be able to understand its output, you could make complete minimal example (leaving as little code as possible while problem is still reproduces) and upload it somewhere - probably someone here will look into it